# Standard deviation of concatenation of two vectors whose std are known

Tags: standard-deviation

Let $v_1$, $v_2$ be two vectors of lengths $m$, $n$ of real numbers.

Let $\sigma_1$, $\sigma_2$ be their standard deviations, and assume they are already calculated.

It is possible to assume we also know the means of the vectors.

Is there a $O(1)$ formula to calculate the standard deviation of the concatenation of those two vectors?

Thanks

Comment: If you also had the means of the $2$ vectors there is a relatively simple $O(1)$ formula, but I don't know of any using just the individual standard deviations.

Comment: I can also have the means if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v_1=(x_1,x_2,..x_m)$ have mean $\mu_1$ and standard deviation $\sigma_1$, and $v_2=(y_1,y_2,..y_n)$ have mean $\mu_2$ and standard deviation $\sigma_2$.
We can write $$\mu_1=\frac 1m \sum_{i=1}^m x_i\\\sigma_1^2=\frac 1m\sum_{i=1}^m(x_i-\mu_1)^2$$
We rewrite the second equation as $$m\sigma_1^2=\sum_{i=1}^m(x_i^2-2x_i\mu_1+\mu_1^2)=\sum_{i=1}^mx_i^2-m\mu_1^2$$
or $$\sum_{i=1}^mx_i^2=m\mu_1^2+m\sigma_1^2$$
Similarly $$\sum_{i=1}^ny_i^2=n\mu_2^2+n\sigma_2^2$$
We can now write $$\mu=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^mx_i+\sum_{i=1}^ny_i}{m+n}=\frac{m\mu_1+n\mu_2}{m+n}$$
and for the standard deviation:
$$\sigma^2=\frac1{m+n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^m(x_i^2-\mu)^2+\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i^2-\mu)^2\right)$$
Expanding the squares we get
$$\sigma^2=\frac{1}{m+n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^mx_i^2-2\mu\sum_{i=1}^mx_i+m\mu^2+\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2-2\mu\sum_{i=1}^n y_i+n\mu^2\right)\\=\frac{1}{m+n}(m\mu_1^2+m\sigma_1^2-2\mu m\mu_1+m\mu^2+n\mu_2^2+n\sigma_2^2-2\mu n\mu_2+n\mu^2)$$

Answer (score 1):

I will assume the standard deviation values you're using are the "uncorrected sample deviation" or "standard deviation of the sample", defined as shown in the [Uncorrected sample standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Uncorrected_sample_standard_deviation) section of Wikipedia's "Standard deviation" article as

$$s_{N}={\sqrt {{\frac {1}{N}}\sum _{i=1}^{N}(x_{i}-{\bar {x}})^{2}}} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

If you're using the corrected sample where the fraction is $\frac{1}{N-1}$ instead, you can adjust the following solution accordingly. Consider the summation part to get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sum _{i=1}^{N}(x_{i}-{\bar {x}})^{2} & = \sum _{i=1}^{N}(x_{i}^2 - 2x_i\bar{x} + \bar{x}^2) \\
& = \sum _{i=1}^{N}x_{i}^2 + \sum _{i=1}^{N}(- 2x_i\bar{x}) + \sum _{i=1}^{N}\bar{x}^2 \\
& = \sum _{i=1}^{N}x_{i}^2 - 2\bar{x}\sum _{i=1}^{N}x_i + N\bar{x}^2 \\
& = \sum _{i=1}^{N}x_{i}^2 - 2\bar{x}(N\bar{x}) + N\bar{x}^2 \\
& = \sum _{i=1}^{N}x_{i}^2 - N\bar{x}^2
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Note I used that $\bar{x} = \left(\frac{1}{N}\right)\sum _{i=1}^{N}x_{i} \implies \sum _{i=1}^{N}x_{i} = N\bar{x}$. Thus, squaring both sides of \eqref{eq1A} and using \eqref{eq2A} in it gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
(s_{N})^2 & = \frac{1}{N}\sum _{i=1}^{N}(x_{i}-{\bar {x}})^{2} \\
N(s_{N})^2 & = \sum _{i=1}^{N}x_{i}^2 - N\bar{x}^2
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

For $v1$, let $s_x$ be its standard deviation and $x_i$ be the $m$ values. For $v2$, let $s_y$ be its standard deviation and $y_i$ be the $n$ values in $v_2$. For the concatenation of the $2$ vectors, let $s_z$ be its standard deviation and $z_i$ be the $m + n$ values. For the concatenated vector, you get in \eqref{eq3A} that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
(m + n)(s_{z})^2 & = \sum _{i=1}^{m + n}z_{i}^2 - (m + n)\bar{z}^2 \\
(m + n)(s_{z})^2 & = \sum _{i=1}^{m}x_{i}^2 + \sum _{i=1}^{n}y_{i}^2 - (m + n)\bar{z}^2 \\
(m + n)(s_{z})^2 & = (m(s_{x})^2 + m\bar{x}^2) + (n(s_{y})^2 + n\bar{y}^2) - (m + n)\bar{z}^2 \\
s_{z} & = \sqrt{\frac{(m(s_{x})^2 + m\bar{x}^2) + (n(s_{y})^2 + n\bar{y}^2) - (m + n)\bar{z}^2}{m + n}}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Note that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\bar{z} & = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{m+n}z_i}{m + n} \\
& = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{m}x_i + \sum_{i=1}^{m}y_i}{m + n} \\
& = \frac{m\bar{x} + n\bar{y}}{m + n}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

You can now plug in the known values into \eqref{eq5A} to get $\bar{z}$ and then plug that into \eqref{eq4A} to get $s_z$.